# Jquery's siblings() doesn't work as expected

Tags: jquery

The following example demonstrates my problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/bff56wup/3/

```
$('.accordion-toggle').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

When I expand one of the accordion question and try to expand another one while the first one is open, the arrow is not changed. .siblings() should handle that but it doesnt.

EDIT: Corrected spelling mistake, error is still there

Comment: `sinblings()`.... Please check the console for errors before asking questions

Comment: No it doesnt, You clearly didnt understand my question!! Reread my Question AFTER the code. There lies my problem

Comment: The above code is to toggle 'active' class from on the siblings of 'accordion-toggle' and it's working in the same way.  Since other 'accordion-toggle' divs are not it's sibling , it's not removing the active class from them

Comment: @Fenrir you're right - I missed the issue with the arrow. I added an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the `.accordion-toggle` elements are not siblings of each other, hence `siblings()` returns nothing.

To fix the logic you can select the `.active` elements directly and remove the class from them:

```
$('.accordion-toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bff56wup/5/)

Comment: Thanks! I didnt even look at the html. But it makes all sense. I tried finding a way to use this .not() but I only found the css selector way of doing so.

Comment: No problem. Apologies for the confusion with the typo in your question.